# Comparing to Images (shape of the sihlohette image)

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, compare

I'm looking for a way to compare a number of silhouettes and determine which two are most alike, obviously I would like to do this in the most efficient way possible. I thought perhaps this could be done using the image magic morphology functionality, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding the function. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#intro

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical morphology is a technique used in digital image processing mostly for performing image shape analysis. Therefore it can be used for comparing two images to discover whether their shape is similar.

Various methods can be used to achieve this. Basic methods are Erosion and Dilatation and the others are more or less based on them. You can use iterations of Erosion with appropriately chosen structuring element (regarding the nature of the images) and obtain basic shape of the image and then compare it pixel-wise. Alternatively you can detect if something remains of the images or there is nothing left each iteration and based on that determine their similarity. This of course works only for some simple cases and more complex methods with some special treatments have to be implemented for common usage.

If you would like to use mathematical morphology for comparing images I recommend to familiarize yourself more with this concept by reading some related materials, e.g. [Mathematical Morphology](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ibv/reader/chapter6.pdf). There are also other ways you may find more suitable for resolving your task but the problem of comparing images is in general a very complicated issue and not straightforward at all.

Answer (score 0):

A [silhouette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette) is a view of an object or scene as a solid shape of a single color, usually black. The shape therefore depicts the outline of the object, while the interior is featureless. It would have useful if you could have given examples of your test images. Thus when we have such simplified case of an image it would good to observe the spatial distribution of grayscale components of different sizes. This is efficiently obtained from the [granulometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granulometry_%28morphology%29) operation in mathematical morphology. This basically provides different scales of connected components in the image. You could look at this [paper](http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~barnich/files/barnich06silhouettes.pdf) which uses the granulometry to characterize Human silhouettes using a dictionary learnt postive and negative human shapes.